# oAuth using application key

Tags: php, oauth, key

I'm trying to connect to a small API using PHP oAuth 1.0a extension.
The documentation is almost empty about oAuth connection, I just succeed in :

- Obtaining a request token & secret through the Request_Token API
- Using the Authorization URL with this token to allow my app and obtain a unique app key

But what about now ? I don't know how to use this application key with php oauth ?
Do I have to use it to convert my request token to an access token each time ?

The following code gives me Bad Request / Bad auth error :

```
$oauth = new OAuth('_MY_CONSUMER_KEY_', '_MY_CONSUMER_SECRET_');
$request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($config['request_token_uri'], '');
$oauth->setToken($request_token_info['oauth_token'], $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret']);
$access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($config['access_token_uri'], '', "_MY_APPLICATION_KEY_");
```

And the error : `Invalid auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)`
Thank you !

Comment: No one knows something to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally it seems that that verifier code is used in order to obtain an access token ; then I just stocked this access token into my code and it seems to work fine.